# How to design services with EF Core properly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing an application in C# using EF Core. I'm trying to stick to MVVM and trying to bring all the logic and interaction with the database to the services. However, there was a problem in data synchronization between several services. If you create a DbContext for each call, similarly:

```
    public ICollection<Entity> GetEntities()
    {
        using var context = new DbContext();
        return context.Entities
            .ToList();
    }
```

Then there is a problem: since the service returns related data - a list of values from the reference table (for selecting from a drop-down list, for example) and the current value for the record, the data received from different DbContext is not equal (these are different instances, but with the same ID). Which forces you to use a single DbContext for the entire service. But if you need to link data received from two different services, the same problem occurs.... In this case, you would have to create a global DbContext or duplicate the functionality of one service in another, which is also not a good practice.
I see two ways to solve this issue:

1. overload the comparison of all data elements on the comparison by ID.
2. somehow inject one service to another so that it uses parent DbContext (I'm not sure about this option)

Which one (or neither?) I should follow?

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions

Comment: @MehmetKaradeniz thanks, I will try to ask same question there. Should I close this one then?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm also new here. Someone experienced will probably come here and respond